# Navigation bar draw over content when using translucent status

Tags: android, navbar, transparent

So I'm having a small issue with the theme of my app. I have the `android:windowTranslucentStatus` set to `true` in the base theme and also have the `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to allow the background image to draw under the status bar. However this leads to another problem with my ListView. Basically it draws under the navigation bar and when you scroll to the end of the list it stuck under the navbar like this

[image]

I'm thinking about giving the listview a `margin` or `padding` value to avoid this but it seems ugly and probably not the right way. Anyone has a solution to this?